# What's the fastest way to get another copy of a (lost) letter from the IRS requesting additional information?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

I recently received a letter from the IRS saying they needed additional information to process my taxes. They need it in 20 days and I somehow lost the letter and I don't remember what the instructions said. What's the quickest way to get another copy?

So far, I've called their helpline at 1-800-829-1040 and waited an hour and also unusuccessfully tried navigating the IRS website (looking for some sort of online account access). Is there an faster/easier way to do this?

Comment: I found this page - http://www.irs.gov/individuals/article/0,,id=96199,00.html maybe the only thing I need is to recover the notice number. Is there anyway I can ask for that information?

Answer (score 3):

You "can" wait the twenty days for a new one. (But that's not your preferred option).

I'd contact the local IRS office, possibly through your accountant, and then make a RECORD of the call (Date, time, person spoken to, number dialed.) Having your accountant involved is another level of "proof."

The local IRS office can, and probably will, "pull" your file and have the contact information re-sent to you. It's possible that they won't. But just the record (including a phone record) of your trying to contact them gives you some protection.

Comment: Thanks, but I was really hoping just to get another copy and complying with their request rather than worrying about 'protection'. Is it that impossible to get another copy of a letter from the irs!? I called my local office, but they don't offer phone assistance. Maybe I'll try calling a slightly further local office...

Comment: @jdj: You're dealing with a bureaucracy. Do what you can. But then protect yourself if you can't. Kind of like at school.

Comment: @jdj The point is: if you're lucky, they'll re-send the letter (or tell you what it was asking for); but if they can't/won't do that, at least you've got evidence of having _tried_ to comply, which _might_ help if they try to impose late-response fees (although given it was your error in losing the original, it may not make much difference).